# Is it possible to modify logrotate path without restarting mysql?

Tags: mysql

I need to modify the path of the slow logs inside the configuration file of logrotate.

Practically i need to change the content of the file `/etc/logrotate.d/mysql`.

**Can i do it without restarting mysql?***

Answer (score 0):

Use this query

```
SET GLOBAL slow_query_log_file = '/path/filename';
```

this will change the path.

eventually you should disable slow log temporary.

```
SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = 'OFF';
SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = 'ON';
```

Comment: thank you , i actually needed to modify the path inside logrotated.d/mysql file, not the global variable slow_query_log_file. I also wonder if it is the same for the err_log  and why there is not the equivalent for slow_query_log